# Limit access to each other's database in Google Cloud Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, roles, access-control

I need to grant access to Big Query to 30 Phd Students in a University on Google Cloud Platform.

Can I give them standalone access to each of them? i.e. One student cannot see other's work unless it is granted.

Creating projects = number of students is not too cost effective.

so can I give 30 access controls to a single project ?

The students need to have full access to Big query (Create, edit, join, download, run) to their respective databases.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should be possible to create a dataset for each student such that they will only be able to see and interact with the data in it. See also the [access control documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control).

Comment: Tried the Big Query User and Big Query Job user roles. 
In Job User role, could not create a table as well as database. 
In User role, could create database, but visible to all added accounts.

Comment: Looks like the scenario documented at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#read_and_write_access_to_data_in_a_dataset, but it is not clear how to restrict the group/user to specific dataset...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document is indeed confusing. Don't grant any project-level permissions. Just as Katie Sinatra said, go to the dataset Web UI, in the arrow drop's "Share dataset", add email and grant "Can edit". At the time of this writing, after you do the above, the user won't be able to see the dataset in the Web UI, but s/he can still do query in the Web UI just fine if s/he specifies the table correctly, i.e. `project.dataset.table`. (i tested it.) The user can also manually add the dataset to be displayed in the web UI. Here is how to do it, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-web-ui#displayprojects.

What i am still confusing is: after you do the above, when the user do a query, who is paying. My guess is the user is paying. If you want the dataset's original owner (the project under which the dataset is created) to be billed, then my guess is that you need to grant project-level BigQuery Job User permission to the user/email in addition to the above. Then, the user will be able to select the project in the GCP console and hit "BigQuery" to go to the big query Web UI, and be billed under the project. (by the way, if you do this, the dataset can be seen by the user in the Web UI.)

Comment: Thanks @Jay, This worked fine. But due to the billing issue, cannot use it as the original owner needs to get billed not the one's who are querying the database. Anyway, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As JL-HN said, it is [documented](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#read_and_write_access_to_data_in_a_dataset) but it is a bit confusing. To give access to an specific dataset, you only need to go the dataset, in the arrow drop it down and click on "Share dataset". Then you only need to add the email of the student that will handle that dataset.

Comment: Yes this worked if the project is shared only using email. But billing is done to the user who runs queries on the dataset (not the original owener)